# which one is better in printing out a function output in php?

Tags: php

In PHP, i have a function that fetch some data from database and output them.
Which one is better ?

1. store output in a variable, for example `$output` and `echo $output` at the end of the function

   OR
2. echo data instead of putting in `$output`, this causes having more than one echo statement.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers so far focus on the most important reason to do #1 : the code is more flexible! EDIT actually you should output the result of calling the function for this answer to make sense, don't echo *in* the function that does all the database work.

It is up to the user of the code/function to decide where and when to place the output on the page, or if at all. It can be edited, it can be compared against other data, it can be stored for use later in the script, perhaps many times over, without calling the function again.

If you echo the data right away, it's effectively 'gone' and can never be used or referred to again. It also means that *when* you call the function is very significant, which could be confusing if you switch to a more templated output system.

Please disregard the 'performance' answer - utter rubbish, and often the variable will be faster for a variety of reasons. As @Charles says, use code profilers as needed etc etc.

Comment: interested to see what your "variety of reasons" are for why an accumulating variable will be faster. I almost always do it this way, but have never had hard data that it is better than any other way. Is it equivalent to ob_start() etc?

Comment: @Steve to be honest that was the least well considered part of my answer. I should have said something like 'it will be very difficult to prove that either method is faster' and also that my personal opinion is that the variable will be easier for any optimizing mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.  If you aren't doing anything else with the data, they they are exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I think most professionals would rather do it the first way because if its passed on to other people after you then it will be easier to read and understand what it is you are trying to output.

Comment: Using extra lines of code is NOT being professional. Rather, you'd use **good programming** habits like the use of meaningful variable names, indenting and embedded comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually suggest a different solution than the two you present: Return the value from the function and let the calling code decide what to do with it.

If you have a single function loading data from an external source, manipulating it and then outputting it, you have intertwined three different functions that most programmers would separate into different areas.

A much cleaner approach is to keep these different functions separate. It will make your code more reusable within your application and across applications. It will make it easier to maintain and understand. Even better, it will allow you to write unit tests for your code, since each function does one discrete thing with no side effects.

Right now, this may seem like more work with little payback, but it is going to bring you benefits in the future.